# Add if statement to jQuery navigation respond to responsive site

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Basically I want the navigation to remain open when the user lands on the desktop page. If the user is on mobile I'd like the navigation to start hidden. I'm using a very basic toggle jquery to achieve this functionality, I hope all that is required is a conditional statement.

As a scripting newbie, I'm still having a hard time grasping how the if statements work.

Desktop:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav').show();

  $('#mnu-toggle').click(function() {
  $('#nav').toggle(400);
  return false;
  });
```

Mobile:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav').hide();

  $('#mnu-toggle').click(function() {
  $('#nav').toggle(400);
  return false;
  });
```

I only have two media queries on the site at 768px, and 320px I'd like for the closed mobile nav happen within the 768px break.

Any help with understanding the concept of the if statement, and providing a solution would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You should use media queries in CSS to deal with this, would CSS suit your needs?

Comment: If statements are [pretty simple](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp). The most basic form is if (`conditional expression`) {`code to execute if condition is true`}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could simply do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($(window).width()>768){
      $('#nav').show();
  }
  else{
      $('#nav').hide();
  }
  $('#mnu-toggle').click(function() {
  $('#nav').toggle(400);
  return false;
  });
```